# Why to use bounded type parameters in generic, if it is accepting child class object by default?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I am using bounded type parameters in generic (JAVA).

```
class First<T extends Use>{
    T s;
    First(T s){
        this.s=s;
    }
    void setS(T s){
        this.s=s;
    }
    void getS(){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

class UseChild extends Use{
    public String toString(){
        return "I am UseChild";
    }
}

class Use{
    public String toString(){
        return "I am Use";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        First <Use> f1 = new First <Use> (new Use());
        f1.getS();
        f1.setS(new UseChild());
        f1.getS();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
I am Use
I am UseChild
```

Till now its ok. I thought I can pass child class object to setS(), because "T extends Use" is there in Type-parameter, otherwise I could not.

But Output is same if I am using type-parameter without extends keyword as:

```
class First<T>
{
//Same code as above
}
```

My doubt is: 
What is special about extends keyword if I can pass child class object to setS() without extends keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `Use` defines a new method (instead of overriding `toString`):

```
class Use {
    ...
    public void printMe() { // Some nonsensical method for demonstration
        System.out.println("printing Use");
    }
}
```

This bound would allow you to call this method from the `First` class:

```
class First<T extends Use> {
    T s;
    ...
    public void getS() {
        s.printMe(); // not possible without the bound.
    }
}
```

---

The way you're using `First`, you don't need generics at all. Using the type `Use` instead of `T` would work the same:

```
class First {
    Use s;
    First(Use s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
    void setS(Use s) { 
        this.s = s;
    }
    void getS() {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The output would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `<T extends Use>` here acts as a restriction. It specifies that you can ONLY pass objects of type `Use` or that extend type `Use`.

Changing to `<T>` is equivalent to `<T extends Object>` - in other words, you will be able to pass any object.

The difference is that with `First<T>` you could pass any object, for example a `LinkedList` or a `JFrame`. With `First<T extends Use>` you can only pass objects of type `Use` or that extend type `Use`.

One way this can be very useful is if type `Use` has certain methods that you want your class `First` to use. In that case you will need to specify `<T extends Use>` so that `First` will be aware of the methods and properties of the `Use` class.

Comment: Thanks.. But I have different doubt. For first time I can pass any object. But I already passed object of class Use for variable f1. If <T> is type-parameter compiler should allow only  Use object not UseChild object for given f1. If type parameter is <T extends Use> then both can be allowed.

Comment: @mynameisGYAN `UseChild` is an object, therefore it can be passed when the type parameter is `<T>`. It extends `Use` but `Use` also extends `Object` (all objects do). So indirectly `UseChild` extends `Object` therefore it can be passed when the type parameter is `<T>`.

Comment: May be I am wrong, but what I am getting is: First <Use>f1 = new First<Use>(). f1.setS(new Integer(10)) is compiler error. So f1.setS(new UseChild()) also should be compiler error if T does not extends Use in type-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The Type-parameter(T) of any generic class accepts type-argument and children of type argument. We can pass object of UseChild in setS(), even if object of class First is created using Use as type-argument. Because UseChild is child class of Use. So following statements are perfectly valid together:

```
First<Use>f = new First<Use>(new Use());
f.setS(newUseChild());
```

Difference between bounded and unbounded types are not as it stated in the question. Actual difference between is discuss below:

If we do not use bounded type, then T extends Object, and s becomes reference variable of object type.

```
class Use
{
        public String toString()
        {
                return "I am Use";
        }
        public void call()
        {
                System.out.println("I am call of Use");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                First <Use> f1 = new First <Use> (new Use());
                f1.getS();
        }
}
```

Lets check various fields of class First:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class First<T>
{
        T s;
        First(T s)
        {
                this.s=s;
        }
        void setS(T s)
        {
                this.s=s;
        }
        void getS()
        {
                Field[] flds = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for(Field f:flds)
                {
                        String name = f.getName();
                        String type = f.getType().getName();
                        int i = f.getModifiers();
                        String modifier = Modifier.toString(i);
                        System.out.println("Name = "+name+" type= "+type);
                }
                System.out.println(s.getClass().getName());
        }
   }
```

Output is:

```
Name = s type= java.lang.Object
Use
```

So T extends java.lang.Object. s is reference variable of type java.lang.Object. We cannot call Use specific methods using variable s.

Lets check various fields of class First With bounded type:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class First<T extends Use>
{
        T s;
        First(T s)
        {
                this.s=s;
        }
        void setS(T s)
        {
                this.s=s;
        }
        void getS()
        {
                Field[] flds = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for(Field f:flds)
                {
                        String name = f.getName();
                        String type = f.getType().getName();
                        int i = f.getModifiers();
                        String modifier = Modifier.toString(i);
                        System.out.println("Name = "+name+" type= "+type);
                }
                System.out.println(s.getClass().getName());
        }
   }
```

Output is:

```
Name = s type= Use
Use
```

So now T extends Use, instead of java.lang.Object. s is reference variable of type Use. As said by @jorn vernee now we can call Use specific methods from First.